# maven-exec-plugin not able to lookup un-compiled classes from src/main/java

Tags: java, maven

I have a weird requirement where source is being generated by a jar based on the source in src/main/java. The final jar should bundle the files that are generated not the files that are in src/main/java.

Here's what I have done:
1. Added source in src/main/java
2. added maven-exec-plugin to invoke main-class from the jar added as dependency and passed required arguments.
3. added build-helper-maven-plugin to add the path to the generated sources to the maven sources.
4. added maven-jar-plugin to include and exclude the required classes.

Problem: When step#2 is executed the main class complains that its not able to find the class which is present in src/main/java. Is it a requirement to compile the class before it is used to dynamically create an instance...like Class.forname("package.Class")?

If maven-exec-plugin is execute after "compile" phase then there's no ClassNotFoundException but the problem with this is the generated source files do not get compiled before being bundled and I see files with ".java" extension being bundled in the generated jar.

Comment: Seems like a case where you really ought to share your `pom.xml`, don't you think...? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your life simpler: use [maven modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

```
root
 |
 +----> generator
 |
 +----> generated
```

Split your project into two modules, a generator module and a module with your generated code. That way, in each modules, you can embrace the standard maven lifecycle:

In the generator module, everything is completely normal.

The "generated" module referenced the "generator" module as a dependency with scope `provided`, and it executes the exec plugin in phase `generate-sources`, using the folder `target/generated-sources/<your generator>` as output folder. You probably need the [`buildhelper-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to [add the generated sources folder as source root](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) also. Everything else works completely as usual.

Comment: Added generated source to project you can use the [sourceRoot](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#sourceRoot) of exec-maven-plugin is simpler...

Comment: @khmarbaise nice, didn't know that